# Realtek ALC889 input devices picking up sound from output devices Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, realtek

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04:

Alsamixer capture:
[image: Alsamixer capture]

Alsamixer playback:
[image: Alsamixer playback]

Comment: I'm not sure I grasp the issue because it makes sense that a microphone would pickup the sound coming out of the computer, external TV or whatever. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation was lacking. The issue i am having is that when i am listening to music it gets picked up by the "microphone". it's not a physical thing since if i unplug the mic completely it the music can still be heard.

Comment: To me it sounds (sorry for pun) like the microphone works as designed. So I still don't understand what the problem is. Are you asking for the system to record all sounds **except** sounds that the system is generating?

Comment: If im on skype with someone and i am listening to a youtube video they can hear it over my voice. i it not to do that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I guess you need to move the microphone closer to your mouth / further from your speakers. However, I have all my mics and webcams turned off so hopefully others can offer a better answer.

Comment: I use headphones, it's not a physical issue since if i unplug the microphone completely and continue to play the music it can still be heard over skype. im guessing it kinda feeds into the outgoing sound?

Comment: Laptops have internal microphones as do some keyboards. Go into **Settings** -> **Sound** -> **Input** and mute the microphones. I read you can also do this in AlsaMixer with F4, Right Arrow key to input source, `m` to mute: https://askubuntu.com/questions/146654/how-can-i-completely-disable-internal-mic-and-webcam

Comment: I am using a desktop, no microphones other than the one on my headset, btw this was not a problem in windows.
I muted the one microphone in input "rear microphone" and it muted the microphone on my headset, but i can still hear music playing even though it is muted.
tested with audacity.