# Camera and Mic permission in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, microphone, camera

Is there any way to lock camera and mic in 18.04 so that apps cannot spy on us ?

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/146654/how-can-i-completely-disable-internal-mic-and-webcam . Although a better alternative would be not to install packages you suspect will "spy" on you...

Comment: Thanks. Does the command work on 18.04 ? No UI method available ? No extensions ?

Comment: I am unaware of any GUI's to disable hardware, As for it working on 18.04, there's only one way to find out....